# WebRTC - iOS Swift - Remove video stream and set uiview to black

Tags: ios, swift, webrtc, libjingle

I'm implementing an app that retrieves a video stream using WebRTC (libjingle_peerconnection library). At some moment, the stream (RTCVideoTrack) could be removed. When this happens in the UIView (RTCEAGLVideoView) still show the last frame of the stream. I want to set that View to black. How can I do it?

For now I'm removing the stream with the following code, but as I said, last frame keeps showing on the view.

```
remoteVideoTrack.setEnabled(false) // RTCVideoTrack object
remoteVideoTrack.remove(videoView) // videoView is the RTCEAGLVideoView UI object
remotePeerConnection.close()
```

Comment: Create a view with black background, then add it in the uiview, initially hidden. Make it visible when you want to remove video. Simple

Comment: On the other side,, add your code in Main thread while removing videoView.

Comment: I already think in that. It's a good option but I'm wondering if there is any other option to remove that last frame.

Comment: try adding empty 'videoView' after removing it.

Comment: Finally I solved with another UIView, hidden it as @aBilal17 said.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue. However, in may case a black view wasn't acceptable and I needed the renderer view to become completely transparent.

Since the video chat view controller in my case is displayed in a container, I was able to make the renderer last frame disappear by completely reloading the container.

This is the relevant code:

```
        // Kill renderer
    vcWebRtc?.willMove(toParent: nil)
    vcWebRtc?.view.removeFromSuperview()
    vcWebRtc?.removeFromParent()
    
    vcWebRtc = UIStoryboard.instance(from: .WebRTC).instantiateInitialViewController() as? WebRtcVC
    if vcWebRtc != nil{
        addChild(vcWebRtc!)
        viewWebRtcContainer.addSubview(vcWebRtc!.view)
        vcWebRtc!.view.frame = viewWebRtcContainer.bounds
        vcWebRtc?.didMove(toParent: self)
        vcWebRtc?.delegate = self}
```

Comment: i think the code from remove this view until add new view took a bit of times, may some view will need to render to this view in this time to, then make crash...